# Django's template cannot get a list

Tags: python, django

When a list render from "view.py", template cannot get this.
This is my views.py:

```
class MyFavCourseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        course_list = []
        fav_courses = UserFavorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, fav_type=1)
        for fav_course in fav_courses:
            course_id = fav_course.fav_id
            course = Course.objects.filter(id=course_id)
            course_list.append(course)
        return render(request, 'usercenter-fav-course.html', {
            "course_list": course_list
        })
```

/urls.py:

```
url(r'^course/', include('courses.urls', namespace="course")),
```

/courses/urls.py:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<course_id>\d+)/$', CourseDetailView.as_view(), name="course_detail"),
```

a link in "usercenter-fav-course.html":

```
{% for course in course_list %}
    <div class="module1_5 box">
    <a href="{% url 'course:course_detail' course.id %}">
        <img width="214" height="190" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ course.image }}"/>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

When enter this page, an error occured:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU8Vy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an oversight

```
course_id = fav_course.fav_id
course = Course.objects.filter(id=course_id)
course_list.append(course)
```

By following you have appended whole course Queryset (even if it holds 1 element it is still not that element as you use only filter)  as first element of an array, which makes course.id non existent or null in template world

You should have get instead

```
course_id = fav_course.fav_id
# Get single course instead of filtering selection out
course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
course_list.append(course)
```